# Spannable Vs Typeface Vs Html

Tags: android, textview

I am preparing an app that contains a checkbox for customizing style such as bold, italic, underline, color, etc...
I am a little bit confused about which method is good for performance. I have tried typeface, but when user selects two checkboxes, it displays the last value only. It did not work well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) is a graphics element used by [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object for drawing text. It specifies the font  (e.g. `Monospace`, `Sans Serif`, `Serif`, etc.) and the style of font (e.g. `Bold`, `Italic`, etc.) and is internally used by both [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) and [Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html).

So the performance comparison should be done between `Spannable` and `Html`.

[Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) is a costlier operation as it involves parsing the Html. 
I used following code with [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and did the comparison between `Html` and `Spannable`. It basically sets the text bold and sets up the hyperlink.

```
Debug.startMethodTracing("htmlspan");
Spanned s1 = Html.fromHtml("<b>text1: Constructed from HTML programmatically.</b> Click <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Link</a> ");
tv1.setText(s1);
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
tv1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Debug.startMethodTracing("normalspan");
SpannableString s2 = new SpannableString("text2: Constructed from JAVA programmatically. Click here.");
s2.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 45, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
s2.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.google.com"),53,53+4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv2.setText(s2);
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
tv2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

### Result:

- **Html API : ~14-15ms.** (org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser.parse API took around 12.282ms)
- **Spannbale API : ~1-2ms.**

TraceView for Html API:
[image: TraceView for Html API]

TraceView for Spannable API:
[image: TraceView for Spannable API]

Summary: Performance point of view using directly `Spannable` is faster compared to `Html`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your research helps a lot...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Spannable internally uses Typeface. Spannable is provided by android framework to ease the development. Hence use Spannable.

Comment: then what about html?

Comment: « *Spannable is provided by android framework to ease the development* » is not an argument since everything else in the android framework – including `Html.fromHtml()` – is probably here for the same reason.